# How to keep records that share same values according to some columns

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Given the dataframe below, I want to filter records that shares the same `q2, id_q, check_id` and keep only the ones with the highest `value`.

input dataframe:

```
  q1                   q2              id_q         check_id         value
sdfsdf             dfsdfsdf            10              10             90
hdfhhd             dfsdfsdf            10              10             80
```

There are 2 `q2` with same `id_q, check_id` but with different `values`:  90,80.

I want to return for the same `q2, id_q, check_id` the line with the highest value.  For example above the output is:

Desired Output:

```
  q1                   q2              id_q         check_id         value
sdfsdf             dfsdfsdf            10              10             90
```

Tried @maxxel_ sugestion:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['q2', 'value']).drop_duplicates(subset=['q2', 'id_q', 'check_id'], keep='last')
```

But it not always keep the highest value but the last one.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['q2', 'value']).drop_duplicates(subset=['q2', 'id_q', 'check_id'], keep='last')
```

should work.

you may need to sort it back if you want the data in a specific order.

Comment: Now I checked and the problem is that now always is keeping the highest value

Comment: @noob4ever thats weird, maybe try to sort first and then drop duplicates and see how the dataframe looks after each step.